# JavaScriptSerializer not encoding Spanish Language Characters (net 2.0

Tags: json, serialization, javascriptserializer

Using .Net 2.0 System.Web.Extensions JavaScriptSerializer to serialize data.

In the following example:

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string test = ser.Serialize("CAFÉ LATINO ' INC");

The single quote is encoded while the E with accent is not.

"CAFÉ LATINO \u0027 INC"

This is causing an error - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when I pass the data to JSON.Parse().

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was using manual JSON Serialization:

```
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();          
    string strResponse = ser.Serialize(branches);

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString());
    Context.Response.Flush();        
    Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
```

The accented characters in my data (and I suspect other non-English characters as well) were not encoded.

I found this article:
http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

I changed my code to not manually serialize JSON and voilà - all my characters now encode correctly.

Thank you Dave Ward!